# Byte Array is not of image format error while converting tiff to pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff

I'm trying to convert a tiff file into pdf using iText API.

Most of the tiff/tif files get converted while there are few which throw the below exception

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat

I tried downloading the file locally and tried conversion that din't work either.

Any suggestions here would be highly helpful.

Tanks,
Rahul D

Comment: Please share the tiff file, and mention the exact version of iText you are using.

Comment: The exception is clear: the file with extension `,tif` that fails, fails because it's not a valid image file. It is hard to understand what you expect by posting this question on Stack Overflow. Your question sounds as: "my radio isn't a television, what can I do about that?"

Comment: Bruno Lowage, Although the question might sound dumb to you, there have been multiple issues while converting tif files into PDFs using iText. A valid tif image was not getting converted into PDF which threw an error saying no documents exist which upon tweaking the code started getting converted into PDFs. So yeah it may appear dumb but there can be something beyond that.

Comment: can you post the code you are using to try to convert the image?

Comment: Voting to close, as the question lacks minimum details needed, like the input TIFF file for verification, any code to reproduce and the stack trace to see where the error happens.